# Управление SVG по его id

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Имеется простое веб-приложение на котором по нажатию на "Насос1" или "Насос2" будет меняться цвета насосов (с красного на зеленый) ,сам рисунок SVG формата . Как это можно сделать с помощью скриптов ?

```
<div id="sidebar">
    <ul>
        <a><input type="button" class="pum" value="Насос1" onClick="myFunction"></a>
        <a><input type="button" class="pum1" value="Насос2" onClick="myFunction"></a>
```

И ИМЕЕТСЯ ID  SVG этого вектора.

```
<g
   id="pump-1"
   inkscape:label="#g1267"
   transform="matrix(0.81036317,0,0,0.81036317,51.74355,-26.659243)">
  <circle
     r="14.303132"
     cy="225.50253"
     cx="-28.786152"
     id="path1216"
     style="fill:#ff0000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:2.4000001;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:bevel;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1" />
```

ВОТ КОД ВЫПОЛНЕНИЯ

```
<script> 
var pump-1Click = document.getElementById("pump-1").addEventListener("click", changeColor); var clicks = 0; function changeColor(pump-1){ if (pump-1.style.fill == "rgb(248, 0, 0)") { pump-1.style.fill = "rgb(20, 255, 0)"; } else { pump-1.style.fill = "rgb(29, 172, 249)"; } } 
</script>
```

Comment: <script>
    var pump-1Click = document.getElementById("pump-1").addEventListener("click", changeColor);
var clicks = 0;
function changeColor(pump-1){
  if (pump-1.style.fill == "rgb(248, 0, 0)")
  {
    pump-1.style.fill = "rgb(20, 255, 0)";
  }
  else {
    pump-1.style.fill = "rgb(29, 172, 249)";
  }
}
    </script>

Comment: ЭТО САМ СКРИПТ НО ОН НЕ РАБОТАЕТ

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для кода, добавьте всё прямо в текст вопроса

Comment: @technoimpextechnoimpex, изменение сути вопроса недопустимо, т.к. делает недействительными ранее данные ответы на предыдущую версию вопроса. Если у вас возник новый вопрос на основе текущего, то вы можете задать новый вопрос, указав в нём ссылку на этот. Правку с изменениями сути вопроса откатил

Answer (score 10):

Для чтения и присвоения *атрибута* элемента, можно использовать методы [`getAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) и [`setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute), соответственно.
Это самый очевидный способ, хотя не очень "правильный".

```js
let circles = document.querySelectorAll('#demo circle[id^="pump-"]'); 
for (let circle of circles)
  circle.addEventListener('click', toggleFillColor); 

function toggleFillColor() {
  let newFillColor = this.getAttribute('fill') === '#0f0' ? '#f00' : '#0f0'; 
  this.setAttribute('fill', newFillColor); 
}
```

```html
<svg id="demo" width="400" height="150">
  <circle id="pump-1" cx="100" cy="75" r="50" fill="#f00" stroke="#000" stroke-width="4"/>
  <circle id="pump-2" cx="300" cy="75" r="50" fill="#0f0" stroke="#000" stroke-width="4"/>
</svg>
```

С атрибутами SVG **в XML**, нужно работать через варианты методов, понимающие пространства имен: [`getAttributeNS`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttributeNS) и [`setAttributeNS`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttributeNS). Методами без "NS" допустимо пользоваться **в HTML**. На практике, этим различием часто пренебрегают (пока не сталкиваются с ошибками).
Таким образом, надо учитывать специфику неймспейсов... и способ с атрибутами на самом деле может оказаться намного сложнее, чем кажется поначалу.

---

Другой вариант - изменение *стилей*: через свойство элемента `style`, или назначением/удалением класса.
Имхо, работа через классы - наиболее удобный и безопасный путь:

```js
let circles = document.querySelectorAll('#demo circle[id^="pump-"]'); 
for (let circle of circles)
  circle.addEventListener('click', toggleFillColor); 

function toggleFillColor() {
  this.classList.toggle('u--enabled');  
}
```

```css
.u--enabled { fill: #0f0; }
```

```html
<svg id="demo" width="400" height="150">
  <circle id="pump-1" cx="100" cy="75" r="50" fill="#f00" stroke="#000" stroke-width="4"/>
  <circle id="pump-2" class="u--enabled" cx="300" cy="75" r="50" fill="#f00" stroke="#000" stroke-width="4"/>
</svg>
```

Когда SVG-элемент содержится в HTML, на него действуют стили классов и во внешних CSS-файлах,  и в тегах `<style>` (то есть, все как обычно).

Comment: Ребята , может кто-то уже работал с svg  и bd  отпишитесь пожалуйста ,потому-что я уже голову ломаю 2 недели , все что хотел частично сделал , осталось управление картинкой с БАЗЫ ДАННЫХ (

Comment: yar85  ОТЗОВИСЬ , РЕАЛЬНО НУЖНА ТВОЯ ПОМОЩЬ КАК ПРОФЕССИОНАЛА

Comment: @technoimpextechnoimpex  как понять `управление картинкой из базы данных` ?

Comment: Я описывал что если в базе данных записываю 1 - насос заливается красным цветом например , если 2 - зеленым , 3 - синим , то есть каждое число отвечало за конкретный ID заливки обьекта .

Comment: @technoimpextechnoimpex  я это понял , я не понял что такое База Данных -  mysql говоришь ?

Comment: Да , брать данные с PHP MY ADMIN например .

Comment: Макс ,может ты как то наглядно поможешь ,а то этот вопрос как-то туго идет ,а в нете  толковых ответов нет ((

Comment: @technoimpextechnoimpex, в работе с SVG я новичок. А правками менять один вопрос на другой (что здесь по сути и произошло) - это нарушение правил SO, и очень некрасивый поступок с вашей стороны.

Comment: Чем это он не красивый ?Причем здесь это ???То что я умею я делаю , где у меня вопросы появляются - я задаю ничего в этом страшного я не вижу .

Comment: Тем, что подменяя вопрос - Вы плюете на старания помогающих участников: получив желаемое из ответов, делаете их нерелевантными (более того, ответы могут получить незаслуженные минусы и тревоги). Что касается правил, в справке русским по белому написано: _«Правки должны быть существенными и **улучшать оригинальное сообщение**, они могут включать в себя: ... • уточнение и/или объяснение сообщения (**без изменения его смысла**)»_ -- https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/editing

Comment: @yar85, ему нужно `управление картинкой с БАЗЫ ДАННЫХ`. Зачем вы пытаетесь помочь человеку через `управление картинкой через JS`?

Comment: @technoimpextechnoimpex, меня радуют ваши вопросы! Всё начинается с желания. Возможно, разработчики баз данных учтут ваши желания и в будущем мы сможем даже управлять самолётами с базы данных, но пока таких возможностей нет, к сожалению.

Comment: Bharata, вы буквально все поняли . Описал я все довольно понятно . Вот как будет происходить весь процесс ...Контроллером будет записываться в BD 1,2 или 3 цифра , от туда считываться и выводить на страницу данные где первый  насос отвечает за 1 (зеленый) , второй насос отвечает за 2 (синий) за третий насос отвечает 3  (красный ) .И в зависимости от того какую цифру запишет контроллер (1,2,3) отобразится соответствующий насос . Чего и нужно было добиться и собственно в чем я попросил Вашей помощи ,а вы на меня налетели сразу .

Comment: @Bharata, до управления самолетами вполне могли бы дойти, учитывая скорость роста аппетитов ТС. Вот как я посмел не написать в ответе две книги по теории и практике связки AJAX, PHP, SQL (а заодно PDO, чего уж мелочиться) - сам поражаюсь.

Comment: @technoimpextechnoimpex, помощь - это когда просящий ее, пытается что-то сделать самостоятельно. Ваши вопросы больше похоже на требования(!) выполнения работ. Но дело сейчас не в этом, а в грубом нарушении норм поведения, принятых на ruSO. Пожалуйста, соблюдайте порядки сообщества, в которое пришли - тогда и сообщество будет относиться благосклонно. Ведь ничего сложного в том чтобы прочесть краткую справку, и каждый новый вопрос оформлять отдельно.

Comment: Хорошо , я все перечитаю и буду придерживаться правил . Я имел ввиду не все сделать , а ПОКАЗАТЬ НАГЛЯДНО НА ПРОСТОМ ПРИМЕРЕ  если с этим кто-то сталкивался ,у вас просто опыта намного больше по этому я и обратился .

Comment: @technoimpextechnoimpex, решение сложных задач не показать на простом примере, к сожалению. Вам так или иначе придется изучить все необходимое для решения, так как SO не поощряет "репетиторство": у сайта другие цели, это все-таки сообщество программистов (обучением с нуля и написанием руководств/готовых решений, здесь не занимаются... для этого есть другие сайты). Но если Вы обратитесь с конкретным и качественно оформленным вопросом - тут помогут: дадут ответ без "воды" или направят к существующему ответу с нужной информацией. Вы уже получали такую помощь, и думаю понимаете о чем речь.

Comment: Я понял , будем обучаться ) Можете тогда глянуть один вопрос и что я там сделал не правильно что данные с базы не хотят отображаться в таблице ?(  Базу создал правильно , привязал тоже норм но не записывается .   Вот вопрос : Вывод значения с БД в таблицу с обновлением самой базы данных